# how to add one scroll bar to the window (easygui in python)

Tags: python, easygui

I am using easygui to create a GUI. But the message I want to display is too long, so that in the generated GUI, I cannot see the first sentence and the last sentence. What is wrong? and how can I see the first sentence and last one ?

This is one example: 
[image]

Comment: Use some kind of scrollable pane, you're lucky the window doesn't stretch beyond the screen edges with this.

Comment: @MightyPork could you give me more instructions on how to add a scrollable pane?